# MySql view records last 24 hour records

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a schedule run at 12:00. I need to see all records for the last 24 hour.
I use this where clause;

```
Where DATE(Date_field) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Now I see only the records from the last 12 hour

```
Where DATE(Date_field) >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Now I see the records from the last 12 hour and the day before.

I've also tried

```
Where DATE(Date_field) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

now I see all records of the past day and not those records in this day to 12:hour

```
Where DATE(Date_field) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 0 DAY)
```

I see only records of the last 12 hour

Who can help me to see records of the last 24 hour.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert your `datetime` in a simple `date` without time

```
where Date_field >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```